# Screen Blinking/Flashing on tab change

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

After I replace

```
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
```

for

```
import { createMaterialBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation-material-bottom-tabs';
```

my screen is flashing/blinking on every `tabChanged` events

Snack
https://snack.expo.io/@avo/reactnavigation-issue

Is there any solution ?

Comment: Same issue with drawer navigation.

Comment: @MudasarRauf Try to change theme from default to dark
`import { DarkTheme } from 'react-native-paper' `